# When you terminate multi display in OS X 10.9 Mavericks, what happens?

Tags: display, macos

Here's a question by a non-developer who cannot touch OS X 10.9 Mavericks, but I hope some developers help me in this issue -

I have one 27-inch display and 15-inch Retina MacBook Pro, and when I'm out of home I use the Retina laptop, and when I'm at home I use Retina but also with 27-inch display in order to take advantage of larger desktop. However, in OS X 10.8, when I terminate the multi display functionality to get it out of home, then screen on laptop becomes messy, with apps being viewed on 27-inch display being scattered around on laptops. That's why I've been considering recently buying iMac and use it on home instead. That said, I hate using two Mac.

So here's a question: When you terminate multi display in Mavericks, then apps on 27-inch display return back to the location on which those apps were before connecting to another display, or are those still messy much like on Mountain Lion?

If hopefully it is the former, then I want to wait for Mavericks and new thunderbolt display… If the latter, then I have to buy iMac right now…

Comment: I wouldn't buy a new iMac just for that...
I do recognize your problem. You could just install an app like bettertouchtool so you could manage your windows better. Don't have a real answer for you since I don't have a osx dev licence.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Mountain Lion there's an awesome app called [Multimon](http://www.multimonapp.com).

Unfortunately it does not work as it should on Mavericks :(